# Will a Safari-based app for iPhone be accepted to the iTunes store?

Tags: iphone, itunes, itunes-store

I'm about to begin development of an iPhone app.  The app itself is fairly basic, and I want a speedy turnaround time.

I'm a web developer myself, specialising in traditional web technologies such as PHP/MySQL; I have no experience in Objective-C.

My plan was to create a very basic iPhone app that is just a Safari service that passes some basic variables to a URL.  That URL is the app built in PHP and housed on my servers, this way I can create the app very quickly without needing to outsource anything.

My question is whether apps of this nature would be accepted into the iTunes store, or would they be out-right rejected?  Anyone's experiences or comments are very welcome.

Thanks

Comment: So, why bother with the App Store? Are you planning to charge for this app? Do you have plans for what you'll do when someone extracts the URL from it, and just starts going there in a browser?

Comment: We're not charging, but the App store will produce a lot of traffic/downloads.

Comment: Such things have been approved in the past. No one can make you any guarantees about whether they'll be approved in the future, or in your case. I will say that, as a user, I'd be kind of irritated by downloading an app that didn't offer me any more than I could get by going to your site (and maybe saving a home screen bookmark).

Comment: Don't count on the traffic/downloads. There are over 250,000 apps on the store, many of them free. Unless you have some marketing plan to push attention to your app on the store, you'll get a pop on launch day that will exponentially decline to the single digits per day. And if you do have the marketing, why don't you just send those people straight to your web site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could go either way, but mind bullet 12.3 from the App Store Review Guidelines:

> **12.3** Apps that are simply web clippings, content aggregators, or a collection of links, may be rejected

In my opinion, a simple `UIWebView` wrapper around your web site comes close to the definition of a simple web clipping. Your approval may very well hinge on your luck in drawing a sympathetic reviewer.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends upon your application...These kinds of application have been approved in the past but again I am saying that it depends on many factors.
Try to test your app in every possible manner and also keep in mind the memory issues.

Best of luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

Should be fine - its called a web app and there is software out there that will do just this for you.

All you need to do is to make a UIWebView and put your web app into it.

Also look at http://jqtouch.com. That gives you some idea of what you can do web-side. :)

http://www.netbiscuits.com/559

> Native Hybrid Apps
>
> Native apps can interface more deeply
>   with the mobile handset modules and
>   sensors to create an even richer
>   mobile user experience. Netbiscuits
>   provides pre-build native apps
>   frameworks for all major mobile
>   operating systems to be easily
>   customized for the needs of
>   enterprises.
>
> Get "2in1" by combining the power of
>   mobile websites and native apps by
>   wrapping mobile websites into hybrid
>   apps and list them easily in all major
>   app stores of providers like Apple,
>   Nokia, Google or Samsung to open a new
>   mobile distribution channel. The
>   benefits of this approach are fast
>   time to market, minimized development
>   and maintenance efforts and maximum
>   mobile cross-platform technology
>   coverage.

Comment: Any examples of this software?

Comment: Answer seemed to miss the question completely

Comment: I can't remember what its called atm - but try looking up hybrid applications. :)

Comment: @amr here is the question "My question is whether apps of this nature would be accepted into the iTunes store, or would they be out-right rejected? Anyone's experiences or comments are very welcome." Now what is the first line of my answer?! The rest of my answer justifys my claim and points the OP to an interesting website.

Comment: I can't find anything on 'web apps', do you have any URLs for further reading?

Comment: The question was asking if a web app would be accepted, not how to go about making one (which I assume, given the question, he knows how to do)

Comment: @amr yes. and I answered that question. "should be fine" is an answer. I can't say "yes" definitely because apple makes a personal decision per app. Then I justified my answer by explaining the process behind the app itself. The jqtouch was just an interesting link I thought might have been useful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be accepted as long as you stick with HTML, CSS, JS and Obj-C on the client side. You still need to wrap it in an iPhone app. In my experience, the best way to this is to use http://www.phonegap.com/ or a similar framework. 
You'll have the option of deploying you app through iTunes or as a regular web app (you users will be able to create a link to your web app right on their springboards)

Answer (score 0):

It SHOULD be accepted, granted you test test test and make it look just like a native application.  Also you'll have to make sure that your server is never down, or if the application can't reach it just display an error message.  You also have to keep in mind that there are a lot of iPod Touch users, and they don't have access to the internet all the time.  Which means that chances are you'll get a BUNCH of 1 star reviews